# How to hide an element in angular js if this is repeatable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a code and I'm repeatable in text with icon.

You see the img but I want to hide to this actually I show this image if I have a anchor link than show if I have no link than not show this image. Is this possible in angular js?

My code is:

**Angular Code is**

```
 var myAppMy = angular.module('myFapp', []);
  myAppMy.controller('myControler', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      {
        "title":"Book" ,"subtitle":[
          {"subtitle":"PanchTantra ",
          "description":"Kids Books",
            "authorName":"Kisna"
          }
          ],
        "description": "Some Book is very Good."
      }, 
      {
        "title":"Mediciane Book" , "subtitle":[
          {"subtitle":"Pharmacy", "description":"This book is related to Docotrs"}
          ],
        "description": "This book is very hard"
      },
       {
        "title":"Reciape Book" , "subtitle":[
          {"subtitle":"Khana Khajana", "description":"This book is related to Foods"}
          ],
        "description": "This book is nice..."
      },
       {
        "title":"Computer Book" , "subtitle":[
          {"subtitle":"BCA MCA", "description":"This book is related to Education"}
          ],
        "description": "This book is very beautiful."
      }

    ];

  });
```

**HTML Code is**

```
 <body ng-app="myFapp">
          <ul ng-controller="myControler">
            <li ng-repeat= "item in items">
              <div>{{item.title}} </div>
              <div>{{item.description}}</div>
              <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="subtitle in item.subtitle">
                  <div>{{subtitle.subtitle }} <a href="#"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/76e03db06bb6dcf24f95bf4d354486db?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />{{ subtitle.authorName}}</a> </div>
                  <div>{{subtitle.description}} this is </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
  </body>
```

**[Plunkr link is](http://plnkr.co/edit/aHvhhm0GRt9ZYhx7Cx6y?p=preview)**

Comment: *"you see the img but i want to hide to this actuallly i show this image if i have a anchor link than show if i have no link than not show this image how it possible in angular js"* Say what now? Can you clarify that? Punctuation is useful, so is capitalization.

Comment: wont it be good idea to remove the duplicates by using underscore function in the controller?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder if i have anchor link as like img right side  "kisna" than show this image if not anchor than not show img

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do ?

```
<div>{{subtitle.subtitle }} <a href="#" ng-show="subtitle.authorName"><img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/76e03db06bb6dcf24f95bf4d354486db?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />{{ subtitle.authorName}}</a> </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6tnGlTLeLUZdiGCUHDFV?p=preview

The ng-show directive allows you to show or hide the given HTML element based on the expression provided.

See the [Official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)